# How to split list into columns?

Tags: angular

I have list of objects like:

```
 cases: Case[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'A' },
    { id: 1, name: 'B' },
    { id: 1, name: 'C' },
    { id: 1, name: 'D' },
    { id: 1, name: 'E' },
    { id: 1, name: 'F' },
  ];
```

and I want to display it as 4 columns in ngFor directive

```
  <li *ngFor="let row of casesRows; index as i;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{i}}</h5>

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I'm stuck with Typescript converting simple list into 4 column list.
My first idea was:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCasesRows();
  }

  getCasesRows() {
    this.i = 0;
    this.cases.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element)
      if (this.i = 0 ) {
        this.cases4.col1 = element;
      } else if (this.i = 1) {
        this.cases4.col2 = element;
      } else if (this.i = 2) {
        this.cases4.col3 = element;
      } else if (this.i = 3) {
        this.cases4.col4 = element;
        this.i = -1;
      }
      this.i = this.i + 1;
    });
  }
```

But I end up with error like:
**ERROR TypeError: "_this.cases4 is undefined"**

Expected Output: 4 columns displayed like this:

> A B C D
>
> E F

as cards

Comment: Please try using `Array.Map` function instead of writing case statement.

Comment: Does this help? Use `*ngIf="(i % 4) == 3"` in the inner div. If yes I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like array_chunk like in example:

```js
var cases = [
    { id: 1, name: 'A' },
    { id: 1, name: 'B' },
    { id: 1, name: 'C' },
    { id: 1, name: 'D' },
    { id: 1, name: 'E' },
    { id: 1, name: 'F' },
  ];
  
function array_chunk(arr, len) {

  var chunks = [],
    i = 0,
    n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return chunks;
}

console.log(array_chunk(cases, 4));
```

Here is an example in angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wplxwm

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

ts

```
  const cases = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 1, name: 'B' },
  { id: 1, name: 'C' },
  { id: 1, name: 'D' },
  { id: 1, name: 'E' },
  { id: 1, name: 'F' },
];
```

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let row of cases; index as i;">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{i}}</h2>
        <h4>{{row.name}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live demo](https://ami-ng-t58lnb.stackblitz.io/)

Answer (score -1):

try this to remove your error.

```
var cases4 = {};
var i = 1;
 this.cases.forEach(element => {
       cases4["col"+i++] = element.name;
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42376222/7251782) question.

The answer was:

1. Install Bootstrap
2. Use class="col-md-4" to get expected result.